# Can Philips Hue bulbs run schedules while the bridge is off?

Tags: philips-hue, bridge

I understand I need the Philips Hue Bridge to control Philips Hue lights.

Let's say I set everything up and configure a light to go on/off on a schedule (turn on light in evening, turn off in morning). Then I disconnect the Bridge (unplug/power off). Will the light still go on/off on the schedule, or do I need the Bridge connected for this to work?

I guess what I'm asking is: Is the light itself aware of the time and schedule, or is it the Bridge which knows about the time/schedule and just sends on/off instructions to the light?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice question, love it!  I've found some information on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Hue/comments/5r420j/once_my_lights_are_set_up_can_i_disconnect_the/).  Someone asked,

> [I am] wondering what happens if my network goes out. Can the lights and switches operate without the Bridge?

The answer given was,

> No. The bridge is essential to controlling the lights. Without a bridge they are "dumb" lights that merely invoke their default behavior when powered on: bulbs to a warmish white light and light strips to their last activated colour.
>
> Without the bridge any kind of color control, or any other behavioral control whatsoever beyond turning on/off by flipping the light switch or unplugging, is entirely unavailable.
>
> The bridge is the brain of the operation. The bulbs just receive instructions from it; they have zero intelligence of their own. Your smartphone can be used to program/control the bridge, but cannot in any form address the lights directly: they speak a different protocol altogether from wifi called ZigBee.

In other words, the light does not know the schedule; it is very much the bridge that sends the instructions to the light.  The light is basically an endpoint in the system with no intelligence of its own: it depends on the Bridge system to turn it on and off.